# Evaluating the right limit of: $1+\sin(\frac{2\pi}{x}\sqrt{x})$ at $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I have a limit as $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \left((1+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{x}\right))\sqrt{x}\right).$$ I am planning to use Squeeze Theorem, so I say that

$-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1 \implies -1 \leq \sin(\frac{2\pi}{x}) \leq 1 \implies 0 \leq 1 + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{x}\right) \leq 2$

$\implies 0 \leq \left(1 + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{x}\right)\right)\sqrt{x} \leq 2\sqrt{x}$

I use the theorem so I get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} ((1+sin(\frac{2\pi}{x})\sqrt{x})=0$.

Is there any problem? Also how can I find the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{x}\right)$ so then, I evaluate the whole limit without using Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there any problem?*

Your derivation is fine. Using the squeeze theorem is a good idea since
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{x}\right)
$$does *not* exist. Observe that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{1/n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin(2n\pi)=0
$$ and that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{1/(n+\frac14)}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin \frac{\pi}2=1\ne0
$$ proving 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{x}\right)
$$
*can't* exist.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not see how can we conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{1/n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin(2n\pi)=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{1/(n+\frac12)}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin(\pi)=-1$.

Comment: Assume $n=1,2,\cdots,$ do you agree with $\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{1/n}\right)=\sin(2n\pi)=0$ and with $\sin\left(\cfrac{2\pi}{1/(n+\frac14)}\right)=\sin(2\pi (n+1/4))=\sin \frac \pi2=1$?

Comment: If $n$ takes integer values, yes.

Comment: If $x=1/n$ or if $x=1/(n+\frac 14)$, then $x \to 0^+$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, that is right.